# booting chromium-os from Disk Image file using grub2?

Tags: linux, grub2, chromium-os

I'm currently using Linux with Grub2 boot loader

is there any way to add the menuentry something like that

```
menuentry 'chromium-os' {
    imagefilepath=/path/to/chromiumos_base_image.bin
}
```

Answer (score -1):

no.  chromiumos_base_image.bin is a full disk image formatted using GPT.  once Chromium OS boots, it expects the disk to have specific partitions with specific content.

if you want to boot a disk image, use QEMU/KVM to do so.